# Github API result

Tags: github, github-api

I use github api to get the details of repository, in the result field, there is "fork" and "has_issue" field, which means whether the project allows to fork and report issue.

In my understanding：  if the value of "fork" is false, then the value  of "forks_count" will be 0, because no one is allowed to fork it; if the value of "has_issue" is false, then "open_issues_count" should be 0.

However, `https://api.github.com/repos/textmate/textmate`
both "fork" and "has_issue" are false, but  "forks_count" and "open_issues_count" are much larger than 0, Anyone knows why?

Another problem is that, the value of "language" is predefined by repository owners or automatically extracted by Github?

Comment: I would assume that fork being false means that the repository is NOT a fork of another repository (I believe it's possible to fork any public repo).
Furthermore, the language is picked up automatically by GitHub.

Comment: @prince thanks, then how about has_issue? Thanks

Comment: `has_issues` means whether issues enabled or disabled

Comment: has_issues refers to whether issues are enabled (i.e. can someone create an issue) for the repo: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/ I think this situation could have come to be if issues were originally enabled and then switched off. (Interestingly you can access the issues through the api: https://api.github.com/repos/textmate/textmate/issues).

Comment: @Prince yes it is interesting that if has_issues means issues is enable or disable, why we still can get the number of issues?

Comment: @taras-d if "has_issues" is false, why the number of "issues" is not 0?

Comment: @sweetyBaby, looks like enabling or disabling issues does not affect number of created issues